# No options needed on checkbox yii2, Only label at the top is required

Tags: yii2, active-form

yii2 checkbox value is not required. Only the label is required at the top in yii2 active form.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways. You probably want to create a `Toggle Switch` or ... .

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'Attribute')->checkbox([
  'label' => false, // <label> is the parent of <input>
  'style' => 'visibility: hidden !important;', // Or display: none;
])->label('yourLabel', ['style' => 'display:block',]); ?>
```

Also if the user clicks on the text within the `<label>` element, it toggles the control.
You can use `yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm` instead of `yii\widgets\ActiveForm` for more options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple tag() method of HTML helper class in Yii 2. As follows:

```
Html::tag('label', 'LABEL_TEXT');
```

Or you can mention only {label} for the template option for that particular field like:

```
$form->field($model, ATTRIBUTE_NAME, ['template' => '{label}'])->checkbox();
```

Comment: This will hide the checkbox input . Adds only the Label. @soodssr

Comment: Isn't that what u wanted? To show label only as mentioned in your query